# How to get a 2 integer values from a list?

Tags: python, list

The program is supposed to return a value[] with 2 values [x, y] given the comparison of the the values within the list.

E.g if a[0] > b[0], a point is awarded to x, and vice-versa. If a[1] == b[1], no point should be awarded.
After the last value has been iterated the final score should be [1,1]

```
def return_score_comparison():

    

    a = [2, 4, 6]
    b = [3, 4, 5]
   
    x = 0
    y = 0
    score_ = [x, y]
    noPoint = 0

    for m in range(len(a)):
        for n in range(len(b)):
            if a[m] > b[n]:
               x = x + 1
            elif a[m] < b[n]:
                y = y + 1
            else:
                a[m] == b[n]
                print(noPoint)

     return score_
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip` for *pairwise* (parallel) iteration of multiple lists. Nested loops give you the cross-product (combine every element of `a` with every element from `b`, not just with the one at their particular index):

```
def score(a, b):
    score_a = score_b = 0
    for x, y in zip(a, b):
        score_a += (x > y)
        score_b += (y > x)
    return [score_a, score_b]

a = [2, 4, 6]
b = [3, 4, 5]
score(a, b)
# [1, 1]
```